# How to send data to ionic 4 when new entry added to the postgree DB?

Tags: spring-boot, ionic-framework, ionic4

I need to send data from Spring Boot to the ionic 4 when new entry is added to postgree DB. When I refresh the page it sends get request to the Spring Boot and retrive the data. But I need to do that without refreshing the page.

```
 fetchAlarms(){
    return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:8080/api/getAllFines')
    .subscribe(transformedData =>  {
      this.finesChanged.next(transformedData);
      this.trackList.next(transformedData);
    });
  }
```

Here is the Ionic Code which get data when the user enter the program or when they refresh the page.

I did some research, with the  zeromq I can do this. However as far as I get, Ionic4 does not support the zeromq.

Thank You Very Much.